# What happens if a int column reach the max value?

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose a huge database. For example I have more than 4294967295(for mysql INT) users. In any column which type is int and auto_increment, what happens if that column reach the max value?

Comment: you can opt to use UUID instead, if you are running out of ids. e.g. `SELECT UUID();`

Comment: ... or pick a larger data type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The int will overflow and you will not be able to insert more records to that table.

Comment: then what will we do to insert new value? is it needs to create new DB with same schema ?

Comment: You should be able and change the data type to a larger type supported by your RDBMS. Code changes may be needed as well to ensure the type in code can support that as well. May databases have long or bigint types.

Answer (score 2):

You get the error `#1062 - Duplicate entry '4294967295' for key 'PRIMARY'` upon the next insert.

Answer (score 0):

An overflow will occur and what happens next is database dependent.

Although, are you sure you'll have 4 billion entries in your database? Think about it. Theoretical limits won't necessary impose problems in the real world.

If you're worried about stuff like this, go with a UUID.

Comment: Of course I haven't. But I wanna know, what do databases do this situations. Occuring an error is make sense? or must have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Error will occur. You can go with bigint (64 bits), that's always better than UUID that is 128b (if you don't need it).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today. In my case, that was a relation column `int(11)` without a primary or unique key. So all values above 2147483647 were resetted to 2147483647. I spent about an hour debugging that issue, hopefully, it's not happened on production. So be careful with data types when defining relations.
But of course, if you have a unique or primary key your query will fail, as mentioned about `#1062 - Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'`